# How to make any changes in a column when there is a change in the corresponding row in other column while looping through in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, loops

1. I want to add a new column 'rate' where the first entry of the day should be 0.
2. If the time difference is 05 mins then it should be 2 else it should be 2.

input:

```
date    time    
20190101 750
20190101 755
20190101 800
20190101 810
20190101 815
20190102 820
20190102 825
20190103 800
20190103 805
```

output should be:

```
date    time    rate
20190101 750    0
20190101 755    2
20190101 800    2
20190101 810    0
20190101 815    2
20190102 820    0
20190102 825    2
20190103 800    0
20190103 805    2
```

I converted time to datetime to get the correct 5 mins difference.
And run the loop

```
df['_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str), format='%H%M')
```

---the loop

```
k = 20190101 
for i in df.date:
    if i == k:
        df.loc[ df['_time'].diff() == '00:05:00', 'rate'] = 2
        df.loc[ df['_time'].diff() != '00:05:00', 'rate'] = 0
        k = i
    else:
        df.loc[( df['_time'].diff() != '00:05:00') & (df['date'] == i),'rate'] = 0
        df.loc[ df['_time'].diff() == '00:05:00', 'rate'] = 2
```

My output now is:

```
date    time    rate
20190101 750    0
20190101 755    2
20190101 800    2
20190101 810    0
20190101 815    2
20190102 820    2
20190102 825    2
20190103 800    0
20190103 805    2
```

I am not sure how to get 0 for 20190102 820

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly: to fix your problem for the change of day you can use `groupby` on the date, that way it will not compare just the time but the dates too (if your column date is your index, this will work, if not change `df.index` to `df.date` in the groupby)

```
df['_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str), format='%H%M')
flag = df.groupby(df.index)['_time'].diff()
df['rate'] = 0
df.loc[flag.dt.total_seconds()/60 == 5, 'rate'] = 2
```

there must be a one-liner to do the exact same, but since you're handle suggest you're new to python, I went the long road to help you

#### output

```
          time  rate
date                
20190101   750     0
20190101   755     2
20190101   800     2
20190101   810     0
20190101   815     2
20190102   820     0
20190102   825     2
20190103   800     0
20190103   805     2
```

Comment: glad it worked, happy coding! (upvote helps a lot too!)